# Conditional Formatting Question - Excel (AND,ISNUMBER,LARGE)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I can't write this correctly.  I'd like to highlight the cells in the `H` column that are a number `(ISNUMBER)` while matching them with the greatest date `(LARGE)` in the column `A`.

I tried:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER($H4),$A4=LARGE($A$4:$A$15,1))
```

`H4` contains `6.93`

`A4` contains `1/1/2020` - correctly formatted as date

Conditional formula: `=$A4=LARGE($A$4:$A$15,1)` works fine, standalone.  The value `12/1/2020` highlights.

Conditional formula: `=ISNUMBER($H4)` highlights the correct values, standalone.

I really need this formula to highlight `H9` as it reflects the `LARGE` date 06/01 and the `ISNUMBER` cell `H9` that has the value `6.01` and the largest date with a number in column `H`.

I don't know where I'm going wrong.  My syntax is bad.  I'm only an Admin. I'd appreciate any support I'm given. Thank you.

ExcelDatasheet:
[image: ExcelDatasheet]

Comment: not clear rules of larger  and largest date, a bit of cinfused.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help.  "LARGE" found the "newest" "greatest" date when I used it independently.  I thought that I could incorporate it into this search as it worked well on a spreadsheet.  Using Conditional Formatting is difficult and my knowledge is very limited. I'm not a programmer, I'm an admin and know very little about this.  I do appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

Formula to find last used (nonblank) row number in H1:H1000 is

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($H$1:$H$1000<>""),ROW($H$1:$H$1000))
```

It seems you want to highlight the last "Number" entered in column H.

Enter the following formula in conditional formatting and apply it to $H$1:$H$1000 (for more rows, change the number of rows in formula also)

```
=ROW()=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER($H$1:$H$1000),ROW($H$1:$H$1000))
```

[image]

If you want to highlight "any" last value (last nonblank cell) in column H then

```
=ROW()=LOOKUP(2,1/($H$1:$H$1000<>""),ROW($H$1:$H$1000))
```

Comment: You are great.  Thank you for the help.  I only recently learned some basic functions.  I used LOOKUP differently and don't understand the forward slash used and thought that LOOKUP returned information in columns referenced.  I would like clarification if you're interested.  I can't make sense of it and am not very good at this. Your response and support is definitely valued!

Comment: Refer [this link](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell) for a very good explanation. .. Also, if you are happy with the answer, please accept it with a tick.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-lookup-function) from the same website for various links related to lookup function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the conditional formatting.

```
=AND(H4>0,ISNUMBER(H4),N(A4)=MAX(IF($H$4:$H$15=H4,$A$4:$A$15)))
```

Here we use =And(Criteria1,Criteria2,Criteria3)

Criteria1: we use H4>0 to filter the blank cell. you can also use H4<>0
Criteria2: we use IsNumber to filter the "-" string.
Criteria3: we use MAX(If()) to find the duplicate number with the latest date.

[image]